# Laravel 4 store temporary data

Tags: php, session, caching, laravel-4, temporary-files

I want  to temporary store a series of array which will be used by next request. The stored information contains some sensitive data which will be used for navigating around that page with ajax call. The data were different from pages to pages. So, I just need to temporary store it for use when user is on that page.

First, I try to do it with cache: `Cache::put($dynamickey, $multiArray, 20);` But this will result in huge amount of "junk" cache store inside the folder even after it is expired.

So, I tried with session flush: `Session::flash($dynamickey, $multiArray);`. This works when user is open only 1 tab of webpage. But if user is open multiple tab of this website, it breaks.

For example:
1. User browse this website on tab1.
2. Then, user browse this website on tab2. As soon as after user browse website on tab2, the session data for tab1 is removed.
3. User come back and navigate tab1 content. The system break, and not working.

How can I store temporary data which will be deleted once it is no longer required, but also works well with multiple tab?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what the application generally does and the whole multiple tab issue?

Comment: I have elaborate it better. Hope you can understand. Thank you.

Comment: The key part here is the ajax call, is that what you need to store the data for?

Comment: Yeah, basically. You got an idea?

Answer (score 3):

So, on the page that actually sets the session data you will need to generate a dynamic key which you can also generate when the ajax call is made. So:

```
Session:put($dynamicKey, $data);
```

Since the server doesn't know if you have multiple tabs open it just processes more requests, we need to distinguish AJAX requests from standard ones. This can be achieved via:

```
if (Request::ajax())
{
    if (Session::has($dynamicKey)) {
        Session::forget($dynamicKey);
        // Do your application logic
    }
}
```

So the session will not be removed until an ajax request is made where you can regenerate that key, now if you cannot regenerate that key from the data provided then you cannot tell apart two different requests. So you will need to get this key to the client side some how such as echoing it into a bit of javascript.

Now the AJAX call can utilise this key and send it in the request, where your server can pick it up and find the correct session of that *tab*.

Hope you understand this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, FruityP. Just one question: how php session works? Does it always store on the memory until it's expired? Or it is stored as file and only accessed when the page is executed. Once the page is finish executed, it will be remove from the memory? Just my little concern about performance.

Comment: Sessions are stored on file and i'm pretty sure when `session_start()` is called (Laravel will do that for you) that it loads your specific session data into memory for that request. You shouldn't worry about this. If you are storing a lot of data temporarily then you can perform the same steps above with the cache instead.